# Yii2 logger not exporting messages from log targets

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm tightening up the logging for our Yii2 application and are struggling with getting the Logger to actually write messages to a log file when dealing with specific categories.

Our project consists of the following Yii2 'Applications' : console, common, frontend, backend and the logging for each of these components work fine for Exceptions generated by Yii and general PHP Exceptions. However when I add some `info` messages for a specific category in the `console` part (which I execute by running commands via SHH) the directory that the file should be in is created but the file itself is not. I see that the newly specified log messages are inside the correct 'FileTarget' when I do a var_dump of it.

I've set the `flushInterval` of the 'log' component to 1 and the `exportInterval` of the logTarget to 1 to make sure that the messages are to be written to the targets directly. I'm aware that this should be set to a larger value at some point, but for now I want to make sure that the logs are actually being saved. Changing the interval values doesn't seem to have any effect.

A workaround I came up with is to manually call `target->export()` for the specific FileTarget. This is how I currently make sure logs are being written:

In the Controller where I want to log message I do

```
Yii::info('Report created succesfully.', 'reports-create'); 
UtilitiesController::forceLogExport('reports-create');
```

The forceLogExport method does this:

```
public function forceLogExport($categoryName = ''){
        $logger = \Yii::getLogger();
        foreach($logger->dispatcher->targets as $target){
                if(!empty($categoryName)){
                    foreach($target->categories as $category){
                        if($category == $categoryName){ 
                            $target->export();
                        }    
                    }    
                }
        }
        $logger->flush(true);
    }
```

This does actually write the logs to the .log file, however there seem to be duplicate entries in the log now and it feels just plain wrong to call an export after every message.

As I read in the docs the actual writing of logs only happens when either these intervals are met OR when the application ends. I could imagine the application not ending properly so I tried forcing this by calling `Yii:$app->end()` directly after logging the message, but the file stays empty.

Since the problem is neither the application not ending (*I can see that it does end*) nor the interval being met (*I see at least one message in the target and the interval is set to 1*) I'm kind of at my wit's end why the logs are not exported. If anyone could perhaps elaborate any further on when/where Yii calls the ->export() method itself that would be a big help.

**EDIT:** added the console/config/main.php settings. Slightly changed my story, initially I wrote that 'the log file was being created but the messages were not being written in it.' but in fact only the directory that should contain the files was created, not the log file itself.

```
<?php
return [
    'id' => 'console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'session' => [ // for use session in console application
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session'
        ],
        'log' => [
            'flushInterval' => 1,
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error','info', 'warning'],
                    'categories' => ['reports-schedule'], 
                    'exportInterval' => 1,
                    'logVars' => [null],
                    'logFile' => '@app/../logs/console/'. date('Y') . '/' . date('m') . '/reports-schedule/' . 'reports-schedule_' . date('d-m-Y') . '.log'
                ],
        [ 
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error','info', 'warning'],
                    'categories' => ['reports-create'], 
                    'exportInterval' => 1,
                    'logVars' => [null],
                    'logFile' => '@app/../logs/console/'. date('Y') . '/' . date('m') . '/reports-create/' . 'reports-create_' . date('d-m-Y') . '.log'
                ],
        // and 6 other similarly structured targets
        [...],
        [...],
        [...],
        [...],
        [...],
        [...],
        ],
    ]
];
```

**UPDATE:** it seems like I'll have to stick to manually calling `->export()` on the desired log target. The problem I had with duplicate log entries (same message, same timestamp) being written was due to the fact that I had set the `exportInterval` property to 1 for the target (which I initially did to make sure the messages were exported at all). I suppose the logger stores messages until the value of `exportInterval` is met and then expect those messages to be written to the targets. I fixed duplicate entries from being written by removed the `exportInterval` property so Yii takes the default value (1000). For my case this would be sufficient since I wouldn't run into those numbers but for anyone reading this please consider your use case and check if you would run into anything close to that in a single cycle.

Comment: Does the console command finishes processing?

Comment: Yes it does, and forcing it to end (by using `$app->end()` or `exit()`) doesn't change the result.

Comment: In console configuration have you got `'bootstrap' => ['log']`?

Comment: Yes. I guess that if I didn't my workaround wouldn't work either.

Comment: Well, show us your log configuration for console then.

Comment: Sure, updated my post.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of here is that log directory has got writing permission so files can be created but file itself hasn't got this perm so writing in it is not possible (which is possible with some configurations) but then some errors should appear... User running console command might be different than the one running automatic log collecting. Try to adjust log folder permissions and see if it helps.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Should have double checked this: the log file is not created at all, only the directory containing it is. Also I've set the permissions of the 'report-create' (which is being created according to the FileTarget settings) to 777 but even that doesn't solve it.

Comment: But the file was created with `forceLogExport` method?

Comment: Yes, if I use that method the file is being created perfectly fine. Initially I was thinking about permissions as well but I assumed both my forceLogExport method and the regular Yii2 logic that handles running the native `export()` method are both being handled by the same user running the same `php` process so I kind of ruled that out earlier.

Comment: Check if the server's user (like `www-data`) belongs to the same group as the user running the successful command with `forceLogExport`.

Comment: I'm not talking about different use cases. See this example gist: https://gist.github.com/benjaminluck/38abfb7264b43274adc44f3ae9cfb1df

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue at some point and I think this should be sufficient enough for your case.

```
    Yii::$app->log->targets['reports-schedule']->logFile = $logPath;
    Yii::info($message, $category);
    Yii::getLogger()->flush();
```

This way you can specify a dynamic log path inside your schedule target and after flush the logger continues as it should.

Comment: Thanks! But this raises several questions for me. For me targets is a numeric array and I can't access the target by calling it's category name like you do, but I suppose that's not the point you're trying to make. Also when I do a var_dump of the target object the `->logFile` already has the correct path, so I don't see any use in setting the path. And calling `flush()` dispatches the messages to the targets, not exporting them right? I have tried calling flush() to solve this matter earlier but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Guess I didint read the whole story at first :P My best bet would be that if you run console actions you don't have rights for file creation. Because flush should force the write-off to files and start from scratch. You could test this theory out by trying to log something in frontend/backend and then doing the same in console action